# Changing default version of postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, dump, postgresql-8.4

I have very frustrating issue...

I have two versions of postgresql installed - 8.4 and 9.1, I have dump of a database made on another machine with postrgresql-9.1 and I want to restore it.

Of course using postgresql-8.4 to do this I get:

```
 unsupported version (1.12) in file header
```

I know that there is a lot questions about same issue, but everywhere the answer is - "change port in conf" or something like this.

But it doesn't help me - I have stopped postgresql-8.4 server at all, but I still can't restore database. And when I log to `postgres` user in ubuntu and type `psql --version` the output goes:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 8.4.22
```

So, my question is how to change this behavior and force user `postgres` to use tools of postgresql-9.1?

And please don't tell me about port - when I type `service postgresql status` I get:

```
Running clusters:
Running clusters: 9.1/main
```

Comment: What operating system/distro are you on? It looks like it's probably some Debian or Ubuntu flavour, so you probably need to read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL

Comment: Ok. So you want to use `update-alternatives` to change the defaults chosen.